# Open source Java filechooser supporting automatic file name extension?

Tags: java, file, save, jfilechooser

Is there a good open source filechooser for java that supports automatic file name extension?

What I want is a filechooser that acts similar to office programs' when saving files; that is, a filechooser which has the option of automatically saving a file with one of a few predefined file extensions. The file name extension should be one those available to choose from in the file filters usually found below the input-field.

The filechooser must also support linux operating systems.

Comment: Edit: I used this solution instead:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596429/adjust-selected-file-to-filefilter-in-a-jfilechooser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this solution instead:
[adjust selected File to FileFilter in a JFileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596429/adjust-selected-file-to-filefilter-in-a-jfilechooser)

Answer (score 0):

Try [XFileDialogue](http://code.google.com/p/xfiledialog/).

Comment: Thanks, but it seems as if XFileDialogue only works on windows?
From what I read on the site, it seems like it switches back to JFileChooser on mac or linux. I'd prefer a solution that works on any system.