# Swing FileChooser / FileFilter

Tags: java, swing, filechooser, filefilter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adjust selected File to FileFilter in a JFileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596429/adjust-selected-file-to-filefilter-in-a-jfilechooser)

I have a [`JFileChooser`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) with a [`FileFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) (`txt`, `doc`, `odt`) and I want to save an existing file.

So I open the file chooser GUI and enter the name for the file to save (e.g. test.doc). After this, I change the file type from the dropdown list to see only e.g. `.txt` files.

At this time, the file-extension from `test.doc` should change to `test.txt`, but how to do it? I cannot add an `ActionListener` to the file filter.

Comment: When you say, "cannot add an `ActionListener` to the file filter," do you mean that you don't know how or that you are not permitted to do so?

Comment: Now I know what to do... - edit method accept from filefilter. Thats it